# Google Cloud Storage Java API - Deleting a file

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

How do I set a "WRITER" permission on a GCS bucket?

I am trying to delete a file on cloud storage using:

```
cloudstorage.objects().delete(bucket, object).execute();
```

and get the following error:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With gsutil, like this:

```
gsutil acl ch -u email@address.com:W gs://bucket-name
```

Alternately, you can go to the [Developer's Console](http://console.developers.google.com), head over to storage > Cloud Storage > Storage browser, click on the "...", then "edit bucket permissions", then click "+ Add item", choose  "user", the email address, and Writer, then click "Save".

Alternately, you can do this programmatically with the JSON API, using the [storage.bucketAccessControls.insert](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/bucketAccessControls/insert) method.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to do this programmatically via the Java API? The link you provided has python options but no java options.

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to do? If your running app has permission to change the permissions on the bucket, it also has permission to delete any object in that bucket.

Comment: I got it to work by changing the permission on the bucket to all users (through the admin console). 

Is there a way to make the java application run as the same user as me (when I login via the browser using my credentials?) Currently the application is running as a different user. I created the bucket using my credentials in the cloud console. So the java app does not have permission to change anything. It has only read access.

Comment: Is this an app engine application? In that case, no. App engine apps run as a service account associated with your project. You can grant that service account permissions, though.